# How to use a Raspberry Pi pin (3.3 V) to reset a ATmega328 (5V)?

Tags: arduino, voltage, raspberry-pi, avr, reset

I have an ATmega328 connected to a Raspberry Pi via serial using a level shifter.

The AVR has the Arduino Bootloader installed and I would like to program it via serial.

What would be the best way to connect the ATmega reset pin to the Pi's GPIO pin 4?

(Keep in mind that the AVR reset pin has a 5 V pull-up resistor connected to it.)

Comment: No free pins on the level shifter?

Comment: @RJR - The Level shifters are a bi-directional BSS138 based setup. Would a level shifter do the job?

Comment: Like this one? https://www.adafruit.com/products/757?PageSpeed=noscript  don't see why not: "and any other digital interface both uni-directional and bidirectional"

Answer (score 2):

A simple NPN transistor from the Reset pin to ground will work. Otherwise a optocoupler (essentially a transistor for your purposes) will also work. (Plus to your GPIO, with resistor. The input pullup is the internal reset pullup)

[image]
<sub>(source: [ustudy.in](http://www.ustudy.in/sites/default/files/images/opto-mup-drain-inp-conf.GIF))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Microchip has a great PDF with simple solutions for converting between 3.3V and 5V, see Tip#7 in http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/chapter%208.pdf

[image]