# Using a 3.3V MCU (Arm) to control reset pin of a 5V MCU (AVR) without a level shifter

Tags: voltage, avr, arm, atmel, reset

On my PCB I'm trying to avoid a level shifter chip. So is it possible to connect my ARM CPU's GPIO pin (which runs at 3.3V) to the reset pin of the AVR chip?

I was thinking of setting the ARM GPIO pin to either low (to reset) or to set it to tri-state (let it float) and let the internal pullup of the AVR take it out of reset...

Do you see any issues with this?

Comment: see answer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180705/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-pin3-3v-to-reset-a-atmega3285v

Comment: I did read that question. Solutions posted there were by adding components. Im hoping to do it just in software... hence the new Q. Should I have just added on to that question? Sorry first time poster!

Comment: Does the ARM have 5V-tolerant pins?

Comment: well you need the pull up to 5V perhaps, so there is one component, the 3.3v device would only pull up to 3.3.  Other than that this is a very typical thing you are trying to do, so yes (so long as the 3.3v device pin is 5V tolerant).

Comment: Which ARM controller?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you see any issues with this?

two issues for you to consider:

1) the 5v pin has likely a logic high level of 4v (5*80%, for ST gpio). so your 3.3v pin may not be able to "drive" it high;

2) if the 5v INPUT pin is every turned into an OUTPUT pin, you may see the 3.3v device being powered by the 5v pin, and the two power sources are shorted to each other, through the 3.3v pin's clamping diodes.

The Right solution is to use a translator, which can be as simple as a transistor;

The Simple solution is

1) to run the 3.3v pin as OD output, and the 5v pin as input with pull-up enabled. Clear the data register on that pin so even if it is turned to be an output pin, it can do no damage; and

2) to use a resistor in between the two pins to limit current when bad things happen - and bad things will happen.

The implicit assumption here is that the 3.3v pin is 5v tolerant. Or all bets are off.

Comment: The AVR's reset pin cannot be switched to output by software. So safe on that side. Tristating the ARM's pin as an (analog) input pin w/o pull-up/down should do the trick - if the IO is 5V tolerant, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** connect the signal from a 3.3 V MCU directly to the AVR reset pin on the majority of AVR processors and have it work. 
You should check the datasheet for you processor, but here is the Reset* characteristic for the ATMega328P from the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf)

From the Absolute maxima on P365:

[image]

From the DC Common Characteristics on P365:

[image]

And from P366 the Reset* pullup resistor is a minimum of 30k Ohms:

[image]

From this data we can say that the required V(reset low) is < 0.1*5 = 0.5 V
...and V(reset hi) is > 0.9*5 = 4.5 V
You cannot produce this output voltage on a 3.3 V rated MCU without additional components.

The simplest interface would seem to be a logic level N-Channel FET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foQQa9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "You cannot produce this output voltage on a 3.3 V rated MCU without additional components." - Yes, we can. The AVR already has the pull-up to 5V built-in. Tristating the ARM's pin will take the reset to +5V, turning it to output low takes it to 0V. Problem solved.

Comment: No you cannot. The pullup resistor will NOT get the reset voltage high enough since the 3.3 V output will clamp it at under 4 volts. Minimum V(input Hi) for the reset pin on the AVR is 0.9 * VCC = 0.9 * 5 = 4.5 V